# Correo vacío al enviar GridView c#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente Gridview cargado desde una base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es enviarlo por correo pero al enviarlo aparecen solo los encabezados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```html
protected void Mail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
 if (SendHTMLMail())
 {
 Response.Write("<script>alert('Correo enviado correctamente');</script>");
  }
  else
  {
  Response.Write("<script>alert('Error al enviar correo');</script>");
   }
}      

public bool SendHTMLMail()
{  
try
{
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
// Sender e-mail address.
 Msg.From = fromMail;
//Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("yyy@gmail.com"));
// Subject of e-mail
Msg.Subject = "Seguimiento a Produccion";              
Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(GridView1);               
Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
string sSmtpServer = "";
sSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
a.Host = sSmtpServer;
a.Port = 587;
a.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "pass");
a.EnableSsl = true;
a.Send(Msg);
return true;
}
catch (Exception er)
{
er.ToString();
return false;
}
}

public string GetGridviewData(GridView gv)
{
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 StringWriter textwriter = new StringWriter(sb);
 HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(textwriter);
 try
 {
 gv.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
 htmlwriter.Flush();
 textwriter.Flush();
 htmlwriter.Dispose();
 textwriter.Dispose();
 }
 catch (Exception er)
 {
 er.ToString();
 }
 return sb.ToString();// al parecer sb siempre es null
}
 
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
 /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET server control at run time. */
 }
```

Lo he depurado y en esta linea Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(GridView1); es donde se envia el gridview y en efecto, solo esta enviando los primeros encabezados:

```html
<div>
<table class="GvGrid table table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-sm" cellspacing="0" ShowHeaderFilterButton="true" id="MainContent_GridView1" style="font-size:X-Small;font-weight:bold;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr class="header" style="color:White;background-color:#337AB7;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;">
<th scope="col">
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado el HTML que produce ese correo enviado?

Comment: revisarlo como disculpa @fredyfx?

Comment: en el cliente de correo electrónico que usas, ver código fuente

Comment: pero que deberia de ver?, solo son los elementos de la pagina

Comment: deberías ver lo que hay en la siguiente línea ```Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(GridView1); ```

Comment: no puedo verlo :c

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91530/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-huntzberger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo resolví añadiendo esto:

```html
<%@ Page ............  EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Y el código quedo así:

```html
public string GetGridviewData(GridView gv)
{
  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
  HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
  try
     {
      gv.RenderControl(htw);
     }
  catch (Exception er)
     {
      er.ToString();
      }
return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
protected void Mail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
 if (SendHTMLMail())
 {
 Response.Write("<script>alert('Correo enviado correctamente');</script>");
  }
  else
  {
  Response.Write("<script>alert('Error al enviar correo');</script>");
   }
}      

public bool SendHTMLMail()
{  
try
{
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
// Sender e-mail address.
 Msg.From = fromMail;
//Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("yyy@gmail.com"));
// Subject of e-mail
Msg.Subject = "Seguimiento a Produccion";              
Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(GridView1);               
Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
string sSmtpServer = "";
sSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
a.Host = sSmtpServer;
a.Port = 587;
a.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "pass");
a.EnableSsl = true;
a.Send(Msg);
return true;
}
catch (Exception er)
{
er.ToString();
return false;
}
}

public string GetGridviewData(GridView gv)
{
      var outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
 try
 {

      using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(outputBuffer)))
      {
        gv.RenderControl(writer);
      }
   
 }
 catch (Exception er)
 {
 er.ToString();
 }
 return  outputBuffer.ToString();







}
 
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
 /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET server control at run time. */
 }
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, lo he depurado pero el resultado sigue siendo exactamente el mismo :C ademas lanz este erro en el catch "Sólo se puede llamar a RegisterForEventValidation durante Render();" del metodo  GetGridviewData(GridView gv)

Comment: Ya lo resolví gracias por su ayuda

Comment: De nada bro. Comparte la respuesta y ayuda a más desarrolladores que tienen situaciones similares o la misma :D y en 24 horas marcas tu respuesta como aceptada