# Ayuda con evento OnDataBound de Gridview para enviar por correo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente gridview al cual le he añadido los encabezados con el evento OnDataBound.
Asi se ve en el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que debo hacer es enviar por correo pero al recibir el correo llega asi:
Sin los encabezados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Evento OnDataBound:

```html
 protected void GridView1_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.None;
                GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
                TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();

                cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                cell.ColumnSpan = 1;
                cell.Text = " ";
                row.Controls.Add(cell);

                cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
                cell.Text = "Total Temporada";
                row.Controls.Add(cell);

                cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                cell.ColumnSpan = 1;
                cell.Text = " ";
                row.Controls.Add(cell);

                cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
                cell.Text = "Avance Semana: " + semana;

                row.Controls.Add(cell);

                row.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
                row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff");
                row.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }
        }
```

Comment: Estas seguro que ese evento es el correcto para definir un header en el grid, si revisas la documentacion veras que se ejecuta por cada row que se enlaza a datos, o sea estas repitiendo el codigo por cada row. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: cual es el codigo que usas para generar el envio de ese grid por mail ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Gracias por su respuesta, pero entonces cual seria el evento correcto para realizar esto?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248719/correo-vac%C3%ADo-al-enviar-gridview-c/248778#248778

Comment: entiendo que el problema es que no vuelves a renderizar el GridView cuando se renderiza para generar el body del mail. Deberias volver asignar el DataSource de ese grid para que el DataBind() lo vuelva a recrear y entonces aplicas el render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que para crear un header deberias usar el evento `RowCreated`

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
       GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

       //codigo
    }
}
```

Algo como esto

```
protected void grvMergeHeader_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "Department";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "Employee";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        grvMergeHeader.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

    } 
}
```

Referencia

[How to add Header and Subheader in Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327749/how-to-add-header-and-subheader-in-gridview/18327885)

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, desconocía esto por completo. Muchas gracias